# Can I use tintable primer without adding tint?

Tags: paint, primer

I bought two cans of [Zinsser Bullseye primer](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/zinsser-bulls-eye-1-2-3-water-base-primer-for-all-surfaces-in-tintable-white-3-78l/1000123375), and only noticed once delivered that they are in "tintable white." This is primer -- not paint -- and the intent is to use it as primer before applying the desired colour of paint.

Can I use "tintable white" primer like regular primer? Or is there something to worry about here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. Tint is completely optional as a measure to cover existing paint or prepare for new color.

Comment: Tinting helps you see where you have painted if you are painting over a white surface